# The right place of Bootstrap's scss files in scss file architecture

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I've read somewhere that when we create a scss file structure having a folder called "vendors" is a good practice.This folder should include our 3rd-party scss partials. Since that part I wonder how can I create a proper structure of my scss files because Bootstrap scss files are placed inside my: node_modules folder - bootstrap - scss. Should I cut and paste the whole scss folder with it's subfolders from node_modules's bootstrap folder to my "vendors" folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably overthinking it. The point of the "vendors" folder is so that you know that the files in it are third-party and therefore not something you want to edit.

In most of the examples I've seen, there is no mention of package managers. They're just downloading the files and sticking them in their project.

I would not advise copying things out of the node_modules directory. That pretty much defeats the point of using a package manager. If you ever updated to a newer version of Bootstrap, you'd need to copy and paste again. You might as well not use npm at all at that point.

If you're using a package manager to manage all the third-party SCSS, you're probably fine with just listing the relevant files in your `main.scss` file. That keeps the third-party code separate from your code. If you need to check what's being used in your project, you can use that `main.scss` as your table of contents, rather than looking at the folders on your file system.

If you really, really felt the need to use a vendors folder, you could populate it with files that would only do `@import` of the actual files in node_modules. But really, I'm not sure that would help you any.

Comment: thanks a lot! You've dispelled most of my doubts related with that subject.